# Daemon not syncing

Tags: daemon, synchronization, ubuntu

My local node stopped syncing. Below are the logs, any idea what is the issue? I'm running Ubuntu.

'''2024-01-08 13:31:17.622  [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1034    Failed to get tx meta from txpool
2024-01-08 13:31:17.622 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1034    Failed to get tx meta from txpool
2024-01-08 13:31:17.622 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1034    Failed to get tx meta from txpool
2024-01-08 13:31:17.622 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1034    Failed to get tx meta from txpool
2024-01-08 13:31:17.622 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1034    Failed to get tx meta from txpool
2024-01-08 13:31:17.622 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1034    Failed to get tx meta from txpool
2024-01-08 13:31:17.622 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1034    Failed to get tx meta from txpool
2024-01-08 13:31:17.622 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1034    Failed to get tx meta from txpool
2024-01-08 13:31:17.622 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1034    Failed to get tx meta from txpool
2024-01-08 13:31:17.622 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1034    Failed to get tx meta from txpool
2024-01-08 13:31:17.622 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1034    Failed to get tx meta from txpool
2024-01-08 13:31:17.622 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1034    Failed to get tx meta from txpool
2024-01-08 13:31:17.622 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1034    Failed to get tx meta from txpool
2024-01-08 13:31:17.622 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1034    Failed to get tx meta from txpool
2024-01-08 13:31:17.622 [P2P7]  WARNING blockchain.db.lmdb  src/blockchain_db/lmdb/db_lmdb.cpp:75   Error attempting to retrieve an output pubkey from the dbMDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2024-01-08 13:31:17.622 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1041    Failed to get tx meta from txpool: Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2024-01-08 13:31:17.622 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1041    Failed to get tx meta from txpool: Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2024-01-08 13:31:17.622 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1041    Failed to get tx meta from txpool: Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2024-01-08 13:31:17.622 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1041    Failed to get tx meta from txpool: Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2024-01-08 13:31:17.622 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1041    Failed to get tx meta from txpool: Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2024-01-08 13:31:17.622 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1041    Failed to get tx meta from txpool: Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2024-01-08 13:31:17.622 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1041    Failed to get tx meta from txpool: Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2024-01-08 13:31:17.622 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1041    Failed to get tx meta from txpool: Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2024-01-08 13:31:17.622 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1041    Failed to get tx meta from txpool: Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2024-01-08 13:31:17.622 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1041    Failed to get tx meta from txpool: Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2024-01-08 13:31:17.622 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1041    Failed to get tx meta from txpool: Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2024-01-08 13:31:17.622 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1041    Failed to get tx meta from txpool: Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2024-01-08 13:31:17.622 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1041    Failed to get tx meta from txpool: Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2024-01-08 13:31:17.622 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1041    Failed to get tx meta from txpool: Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2024-01-08 13:31:17.622 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1041    Failed to get tx meta from txpool: Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2024-01-08 13:31:17.622 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1041    Failed to get tx meta from txpool: Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2024-01-08 13:31:17.622 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1041    Failed to get tx meta from txpool: Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2024-01-08 13:31:17.623 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1041    Failed to get tx meta from txpool: Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2024-01-08 13:31:17.623 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1041    Failed to get tx meta from txpool: Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2024-01-08 13:31:17.623 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1041    Failed to get tx meta from txpool: Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2024-01-08 13:31:17.623 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1041    Failed to get tx meta from txpool: Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2024-01-08 13:31:17.623 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1041    Failed to get tx meta from txpool: Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2024-01-08 13:31:17.623 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1041    Failed to get tx meta from txpool: Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2024-01-08 13:31:17.623 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1041    Failed to get tx meta from txpool: Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2024-01-08 13:31:17.623 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1041    Failed to get tx meta from txpool: Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2024-01-08 13:31:17.623 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1041    Failed to get tx meta from txpool: Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2024-01-08 13:31:17.623 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1041    Failed to get tx meta from txpool: Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2024-01-08 13:31:17.623 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1041    Failed to get tx meta from txpool: Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2024-01-08 13:31:17.623 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1041    Failed to get tx meta from txpool: Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2024-01-08 13:31:17.623 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1041    Failed to get tx meta from txpool: Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2024-01-08 13:31:17.623 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1041    Failed to get tx meta from txpool: Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2024-01-08 13:31:17.623 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1041    Failed to get tx meta from txpool: Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2024-01-08 13:31:17.623 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1041    Failed to get tx meta from txpool: Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2024-01-08 13:31:17.623 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1041    Failed to get tx meta from txpool: Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2024-01-08 13:31:17.623 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1041    Failed to get tx meta from txpool: Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2024-01-08 13:31:17.623 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1041    Failed to get tx meta from txpool: Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2024-01-08 13:31:17.623 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1041    Failed to get tx meta from txpool: Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2024-01-08 13:31:17.623 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1041    Failed to get tx meta from txpool: Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2024-01-08 13:31:17.623 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1041    Failed to get tx meta from txpool: Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2024-01-08 13:31:17.623 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1041    Failed to get tx meta from txpool: Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2024-01-08 13:31:17.623 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1041    Failed to get tx meta from txpool: Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2024-01-08 13:31:17.623 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1041    Failed to get tx meta from txpool: Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2024-01-08 13:31:17.623 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1041    Failed to get tx meta from txpool: Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2024-01-08 13:31:17.623 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1041    Failed to get tx meta from txpool: Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2024-01-08 13:31:17.623 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1041    Failed to get tx meta from txpool: Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2024-01-08 13:31:17.623 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain.db   src/blockchain_db/blockchain_db.cpp:1041    Failed to get tx meta from txpool: Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2024-01-08 13:31:17.623 [P2P7]  ERROR   txpool  src/cryptonote_core/tx_pool.cpp:306 Error adding transaction to txpool: Error adding txpool tx metadata to db transaction: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2024-01-08 13:31:17.623 [P2P7]  WARNING blockchain.db.lmdb  src/blockchain_db/lmdb/db_lmdb.cpp:75   Failed to query m_blocks: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2024-01-08 13:31:17.623 [P2P7]  ERROR   cn  src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:1115    Exception at [core::handle_incoming_txs()], what=Failed to query m_blocks: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2024-01-08 13:31:17.623 [P2P7]  WARNING blockchain.db.lmdb  src/blockchain_db/lmdb/db_lmdb.cpp:75   Failed to commit a transaction to the db: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2024-01-08 13:31:17.623 [P2P7]  ERROR   blockchain  src/cryptonote_core/blockchain.cpp:4826 Exception in cleanup_handle_incoming_blocks: Failed to commit a transaction to the db: MDB_BAD_TXN:'''